# JSON Response validation based on a CSV data

Tags: rest, jmeter, integration-testing, soapui, postman

I have a REST service which will give a JSON response as below

{
"id": 1,
"first_name": "George",
"last_name": "Bluth",
"avatar": "Test1"
},

{
"id": 2,
"first_name": "Janet",
"last_name": "Weaver",
"avatar": "Test2"
},

{
"id": 3,
"first_name": "Emma",
"last_name": "Wong",
"avatar": "Test3"
}

I want to compare these response against a SQL/Oracle DB to check the data is coming correctly (Data from the DB is extracted to a CSV file that is the base lined data)

My questions:

- Is there any way to export the response body into a CSV format as an automated way? - so that i can compare both CSVs
- Any way to read the data cell by cell from the **csv file** to go through each **JSON array** in the Response body for the validation
- Please suggest a proper way to do this if the above points cannot be done with any tools. I have tried many API Testing tools but no luck

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the response in form of CSV into the file just add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def csvFile = new File('/path/to/csv/file')
json.each {entry ->
    csvFile << entry.getValue() + ','
}
csvFile << System.getProperty('line.separator')
```

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Also be aware that you can perform assertions directly using:

- [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to read individual values (or whole response from the HTTP Request)
- [JDBC PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor) to read individual values from the database
- [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to compare the values

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri for your response. In my case I am not able use Jmeter due to the AD authorization. So I used Postman and found a way to read the CSV data and compared with each of the JSON response array.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem for JMeter to bypass AD authorization given properly configured [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager), check out [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more information on configuration details for NTLM and Kerberos schemes

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried your groovy scriptsinto JMeter JSR223 PostProcessor assertion. however, I am getting a CSV file with the Response header not the Response Body. Is there any way to output the JSON Response body.